# Pause issue with Carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am following the below forum and trying to implement the Pause functionality in my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/t9v1dwey/

When I put the code in my HTML , it is coming like below.

[image]

I have described the code in sinnept

```js
$(function() {
  /* Initialize Carousel */
  var paused = 0;
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 1000,
    pause: 0
  });

  /* Play trigger */
  $('#toggleCarousel').click(function() {
    var state = (paused) ? 'cycle' : 'pause';
    paused = (paused) ? 0 : 1;
    $('#myCarousel').carousel(state);
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-play fa-pause');
  });
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.img-title {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.43;
  filter: alpha(opacity=43);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <button id="toggleCarousel"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></button>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <div class="img-title">Chania This is an Image</div>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <div class="img-title">Some other text discription goes at the top that goes a distance across the top</div>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <div class="img-title">an Image of Flower</div>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <div class="img-title">Keep this to the Description</div>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The expected result should be same as below.

http://jsfiddle.net/t9v1dwey/

Comment: Is that your fiddle? Can you put your code in fiddle? Are you using the same bootstrap version

Comment: Are you embedding bootstrap CSS, bootstrap JS and jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Well... it looks like you haven't included some important resourses

You need to included Bootstrap, jQuery and font-awsome.

Comment: Yes , I have added below in my HTML and it is coming fine as expected.             
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @sonu from your above comment: you are missing the protocol (https) or at least missing // in front of the URLs plus you are missing the bootstrap javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`bootstrap.min.css`, `fontawesome` these libraries were missing in your code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```js
$(function() {
  /* Initialize Carousel */
  var paused = 0;
  $('#myCarousel.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 1000,
    pause: 0
  });

  /* Play trigger */
  $('#toggleCarousel').click(function() {
    var state = (paused) ? 'cycle' : 'pause';
    paused = (paused) ? 0 : 1;
    $('#myCarousel').carousel(state);
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-play fa-pause');
  });
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.img-title {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.43;
  filter: alpha(opacity=43);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <button id="toggleCarousel"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></button>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <div class="img-title">Chania This is an Image</div>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <div class="img-title">Some other text discription goes at the top that goes a distance across the top</div>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <div class="img-title">an Image of Flower</div>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <div class="img-title">Keep this to the Description</div>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```